# Install Play 2.0 thru macports

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, osx-mountain-lion, macports

When I do `sudo port install play` my computer installs `Play 1.2.5`. How do I install `Play 2.0` using `macports`? I am using `Mountain Lion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into this a bit more, [it looks like it's not possible right now.](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=play)

Comment: btw, it is available in homebrew. But no real reason to install homebrew just to install Play, it just unpacks zip and installs symlink to `play` executable.

Answer (score 2):

There is no any sensible reason for using any package manager for ... installing Play.

De facto on MacOS and on the other systems, process of installing it's just unzipping downloaded file and optionally setting the path as described in [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Installing).

3 steps:

- check if you have correct version of JDK installed, and install from Oracle's site if required
- Unpack binaries
- Set the path, or...
- You can also create symlink in `/usr/bin` to Play's executable script:

  ```
  cd /usr/bin
  sudo ln -s /full/path/tu/unziped-folder/play play
  ```